# Echo two SQL query results on a table

Tags: mysql, echo

I have the following code:

```
<?php
  include_once '../includes/db.inc.php';
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM clients ORDER BY nif_id ASC;";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
  $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

  if ($resultCheck > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      $first = $row["prm_nome"];
      $last = $row["apelido"];
      $phone = $row['nmr_tlm'];
      $email = $row['mail'];
      $nif = $row['nif_id'];
      $flight = "SELECT flight_id FROM flights INNER JOIN clients ON flights.nif_id=clients.nif_id";

      echo '<tr>';
      echo '<td><a href="detail.php?id='. $nif . '">'.$nif.'</a></td>';
      echo '<td>'.$first.'</td>';
      echo '<td>'.$last.'</td>';
      echo '<td>'.$phone.'</td>';
      echo '<td>'.$email.'</td>';
      echo '<td><a href="../flights/detail.php?id='. $flight . '">'.$flight.'</a></td>';
      echo '</tr>';
    }
  }
 ?>
```

I need to echo the result of the `SELECT flight_id FROM flights INNER JOIN clients ON flights.nif_id=clients.nif_id` query. But when I save the file, what I get on the page is a link with that query instead of the result.

Should I start a new `$sql =` with that query under the first `$sql =`? 
Or is there other way?

I tried `UNION` and `SELECT *, flight_id FROM flights INNER JOIN clients ON flights.nif_id=clients.nif_id FROM clients ORDER BY nif_id ASC;` but then I get `mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given`.

Comment: You're never executing the `$flight` query.

Comment: Is the inner query supposed to be dependent on the row from the outer query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need two queries. Just use the joined query.

```
<?php
include_once '../includes/db.inc.php';
$sql = "SELECT c.prm_nome, c.apelido, c.nmr_tlm, c.mail, c.nif_id, f.flight_id
        FROM clients c
        JOIN flights f ON f.nif_id = c.nif_id
        ORDER BY c.nif_id ASC;";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
$resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if ($resultCheck > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $first = $row["prm_nome"];
        $last = $row["apelido"];
        $phone = $row['nmr_tlm'];
        $email = $row['mail'];
        $nif = $row['nif_id'];
        $flight = $row['flight_id'];

        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td><a href="detail.php?id='. $nif . '">'.$nif.'</a></td>';
        echo '<td>'.$first.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$last.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$phone.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$email.'</td>';
        echo '<td><a href="../flights/detail.php?id='. $flight . '">'.$flight.'</a></td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I still get `mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given`

Comment: @Always Sunny solution worked out. Now I'll try to understand what I need to change on `echo '<td><a href="../flights/detail.php?id='. $flight . '">'.$flight.'</a></td>';`. Thank you!

Comment: I had a typo, `ORDER BY cnif_id` should be `ORDER BY c.nif_id`. Try this now.

Comment: His solution will print all clients' flights with each client, not just the flights for that client.

Comment: just tried your code and it still gives me `mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given`.

Comment: I added the `echo mysqli_error($conn)` but it's not printing anything

Comment: You must be doing something wrong. "bool given" means that `mysqli_query()` returned `FALSE`, which means there was an error, and `mysqli_error` will print the reason.

Comment: Do it like in my answer: `$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));`

Comment: Just fixed the `mysqli_error`, I was putting it in the wrong place. The code is working, you had a typo on `c.nmr_tim`, it's supposed to be `c.nmr_tlm`

Comment: thanks for your help! I'm now trying to show everything on the backend, not just that one client information. I can I do that?

Comment: There's nothing in this code that limits it to just one client.

Comment: I have multiple clients, bookings and flights on the database, but this code is only printing one of them.

Comment: Ok, just figured out what's going on. If I only a flight or a booking for a client, it won't show the client, I need both. Is there a way to show the client if I only have either the flight or the booking?

Comment: Join with a subquery that gets a UNION of `flights` and `bookings`.